# What is the correct type for my WorkflowFoundationApp?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

I refactor an existing APP to use WFE 4.5. The APP runs in an endless loop and fetches new workitems via polling from a third party host via webservice. The app is multi tenant, where each tenant can have its own workflow.

I read so far that there is a WorkflowInvoker, which is designed to unit test workflows. I am not sure if this does fit my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options that you can use: `WorkflowInvoker` and `WorkflowApplication`.

`WorkflowInvoker` provides a simple way for invoking a workflow as if it were a method call and can be used only for workflows that do not use persistence. `WorkflowApplication` provides a richer model for executing workflows that includes notification of lifecycle events, execution control, bookmark resumption, and persistence.

If you don't need features from `WorkflowApplication` it is easier to use `WorkflowInvoker`.